# VBA Code does not work when I try to submit multiple entries at once

Tags: vba, excel

I have this piece of VBA code that works whenever I paste **one** entry into column 16 (see code below).

However, it gives me a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" whenever I drag down the value "Keep - Not Action" or if I paste for multiple entries.

If you have any idea on how to fix let me know!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim r As Integer
 If Target.Column = 17 Then
    If Target = "Keep - no action" Then
        r = Target.Row

        Cells(r, "T").Value = Cells(r, "N").Value
        Cells(r, "T").AutoFill Destination:=Range("T" & r & ":AC" & r), Type:=xlFillSeries 'Type:=xlFillDefault
    End If

    If Target = "req" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter new line item below"
    End If

 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Target only works for 1 range at a time, you would have to loop through the ranges. At the beginning of the code use `if target.count>1 then exit sub` that should solve the error

Comment: Hi Davesexcel, I tried the line of code but it really just takes away the notification instead of applying the autofull into the cells. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using INTERSECT function for your range and target anywhere, Tweak the below code for your use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng as range
set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet name").Range("P1",Range("P1048576").End(xlup))    
 Dim r As Integer
If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
    For Each Target In rng 
If Target.Column = 17 Then
        If Target = "Keep - no action" Then
            r = Target.Row

            Cells(r, "T").Value = Cells(r, "N").Value
            Cells(r, "T").AutoFill Destination:=Range("T" & r & ":AC" & r), Type:=xlFillSeries 'Type:=xlFillDefault
        End If

        If Target = "req" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter new line item below"
        End If

     End If
Next Target
end if   
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, this code stopped the program from working entirely. I tweaked it for the sheet as well but now there is no functionality to the code at all.

Comment: What do you mean stopped ? Is there any specific error coming now.Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to autofill.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column <> 17 Then Exit Sub
    r = Target.Row
    If Target = "Keep - no action" Then
        Range("T" & r & ":AC" & r) = Cells(r, "N").Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Possibly loop through each cell could work,

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rws As Long, rng As Range, c As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    rws = Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 17), Cells(rws, 17))
    If Target.Column <> 17 Then Exit Sub

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        r = c.Row
        If c = "Keep - no action" Then
            Range("T" & r & ":AC" & r) = Cells(r, "N").Value
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Daves, it worked but I still get the same error as before when I try to drag down the "Keep - no action" value. Is there a way to be able to drag down that value and still have excel auto populate the columns T:AC

Comment: Probably not with Worksheet_change, dragging is basically copy and pasting, doesn't work so well with worksheet_change

Comment: How would Disable Events work? Are you referring to using the fill handle?